# Parsing through text to find html tags in Ruby 1.9.x

Tags: ruby, string, text-parsing

I want to be able to match text in between two tags, starting at an opening tag and ending in a closing tag.

Say I have this block of text in a variable called 'text':

```
some text some text some text some text some text
<some_tag>
  some text some text some text some text some text
</some_tag>
some text some text some text some text some text
```

I want to parse the contents 'text' doing nothing until it finds an opening tag, in this case 'some_tag', and once it finds an opening tag I want it to capture everything until the tag closes.

I've been fooling around with blocks and regular expressions for about an hour now and cannot seem to figure out a good way to work this out.

I'd appreciate any and all pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a parser for HTML. Regex and HTML tends to make a volatile mix, that leads to insanity in large doses.

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
some text some text some text some text some text
<p>
  some text some text some text some text some text
</p>
some text some text some text some text some text
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)

puts doc.search('p').map { |n| n.inner_text }

>>   some text some text some text some text some text
```

This is searching through the HTML fragment, looking for `<p>` tags. For each one it finds it'll extract the inner text.

I'm using Nokogiri's CSS mode, by using `"p"`. I could use XPath instead, but CSS is understood by more people.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into Nokogiri multiple times, but I've so far found the documentation to be very poor. But that just is what I've seen directly from the nokogiri.org site. Do you have any good references for it? Thanks!

Comment: @Rhinoo, The docs aren't too bad. At least they have them, which is more than some of Ruby's core libraries. Your best bet is to read their tutorials, nose around in all the docs on their site, and then also go search for interesting subjects on the Nokokiri-Talk mail list. Their mail list is their primary support and the place the developers monitor, so you'll get really good examples of how to do things straight from the people who know it best.